# Unable to connect Angular 8 app call a custom web api authorize endpoint authenticated from Azure AD

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, implicit-grant

I have an Angular 8 app hosted inside an Azure App Service, that I have got authentication using MSAL and the tokens are being passed to another Azure App Service which is hosting my custom web api (.net core 3.1).

I call a not authorized endpoint and it works, but when I call an authorized end point I get different errors, latest one coming is

`System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]`

I have configured App Registrations for both apps with implicit grant enabled and Id and access tokens are also enabled, and its a multitenant application.

**API Config**

[image]

[image]

**Angular config**

[image]

Comment: Please do not add to your questions how long you have been stuck. The only purpose of such additions is to indicate distress to readers and hope that they can be coerced into helping you quickly. Given that most helpers here are volunteers, that is probably inappropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your API for token validation logic. Also make sure token in getting sent in request header.

Comment: Added my app configuration (api and angular)